# router based on select

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have piece of code which looks proper but behaviour says something different. I am trying to get the value selected by the user in this code:

```
  <mat-form-field name="selectPagination">
    <mat-select  (selectionChange)="selectAndRoute($event.value)">
      <mat-option  [value]="five">5</mat-option>
      <mat-option  [value]="ten">10</mat-option>
      <mat-option  [value]="twentyFive">25</mat-option>
      <mat-option  [value]="oneHundred">100</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and this outputs undefined:

```
selectAndRoute(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: why dont you try `"selectAndRoute($event)"` log that value and see what you get

Comment: Value, not [value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use property binding on `mat-option`.

```
<mat-form-field name="selectPagination">
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" (selectionChange)="selectAndRoute()">
    <mat-option  value="five">5</mat-option>
    <mat-option  value="ten">10</mat-option>
    <mat-option  value="twentyFive">25</mat-option>
    <mat-option  value="oneHundred">100</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
  selected: any;

  selectAndRoute() {
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aubbxs?file=src/app/select-overview-example.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

When you are using string, it should be **`value`** not **`[value]`** and you could just use **`selectAndRoute($event)`**

```
  <mat-form-field name="selectPagination">
    <mat-select  (selectionChange)="selectAndRoute($event)">
      <mat-option  value="five">5</mat-option>
      <mat-option  value="ten">10</mat-option>
      <mat-option  value="twentyFive">25</mat-option>
      <mat-option  value="oneHundred">100</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```